# Swift - iCloud Core Data repeats previously added data before syncing

Tags: swift, core-data, icloud

I don't know how to explain in the Title with words this situation: I add information in Core Data (DEFAULT SETTINGS) if the App is started for first time. For now it's ok, iCloud Account is merged I receive `Using local storage: 1` and `Using local storage: 0` now I'm using iCloud and the information in Core Data is merged with my iCloud Account. And when I run app on other device with the same iCloud Account my app adds the DEFAULT SETTINGS and when iCloud send me `Using local storage: 0` DEFAULT SETTINGS from 1st device are addded in 2nd device and I have the same values twice. My DEFAULT SETTINGS are added 2 times :D...
How to prevent that ?

Answer (score 2):

When using iCloud with Core Data you need to detect duplicates yourself and handle them in whatever way makes sense for your app. Core Data doesn't care if you create duplicate entries, so if your app copies built-in data to its persistent store on multiple devices, iCloud will happily give you duplicates. If you use 3 devices you get 3 copies, etc.

To do this you need to observe `NSPersistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChangesNotification`, look for duplicates, and remove them. Since you're using built-in app data that should have fixed, known values, you can probably find them easily them by looking at the `userInfo` dictionary on that notification. Keep in mind that when you receive this notification, **those objects have already been inserted**, so you do actually need to delete them to prevent duplicates.

For duplicates not related to pre-populated data, it's more difficult but not impossible. That doesn't sound like it's your situation, but just in case, here's a blog post I did a while ago explaining it: http://www.atomicbird.com/blog/icloud-complications-part-2

Comment: persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges works only when I add something on another device and imports it to current. When I start app for first time on other device I didn't receive persistentStoreDidImportUbiquitousContentChanges notification and iCloud automatically add my data from first device and the data repeats...